# Unit testing kafkastreams topology based on system time

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to unittest kafka streams app where I have a Transformer and scheduled task.

```
public class  Transformer implements Transformer<String, Info, KeyValue<String, Event>> {
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {

       context.schedule(Duration.ofSeconds(5), PunctuationType.WALL_CLOCK_TIME,  Operator::doWork);
    }

}
```

the logic of `doWork` involves checking the date of one of the date fields of the `Info` to a `SystemTime`

The problem starts when In test class

```
topologyTestDriver.advanceWallClockTime(Duration.ofMinutes(1));
```

This advances the time and triggers the scheduler but not advances the system time of course.

How to deal with that?